# Sorl thumbnail error: Requested setting DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE, but settings are not configured

Tags: django, sorl-thumbnail

Getting this error from sorl.thumbnail version 12.3 when I try to import a model from shell.

```
ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

but the site runs okay from runserver.

full error log

```
In [1]: from gallery.models import Image
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImproperlyConfigured                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-ffea958a5ee6> in <module>()
----> 1 from gallery.models import Image

/home/samuel/Documents/code/revamp/gallery/models.py in <module>()
      2 
      3 from django.db import models
----> 4 from sorl.thumbnail import ImageField
      5 from django.contrib.humanize.templatetags.humanize import intword
      6 from django.template.defaultfilters import truncatechars

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sorl/thumbnail/__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from sorl.thumbnail.fields import ImageField
      2 from sorl.thumbnail.shortcuts import get_thumbnail, delete
      3 from sorl import __version__
      4 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sorl/thumbnail/fields.py in <module>()
      6 from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
      7 
----> 8 from sorl.thumbnail import default
      9 
     10 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sorl/thumbnail/default.py in <module>()
      1 from django.utils.functional import LazyObject
      2 
----> 3 from sorl.thumbnail.conf import settings
      4 from sorl.thumbnail.helpers import get_module_class
      5 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sorl/thumbnail/conf/__init__.py in <module>()
      1 from django.conf import settings as user_settings
      2 from django.utils.functional import LazyObject
----> 3 from sorl.thumbnail.conf import defaults
      4 
      5 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sorl/thumbnail/conf/defaults.py in <module>()
     29 
     30 # Storage for the generated thumbnails
---> 31 THUMBNAIL_STORAGE = settings.DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE
     32 
     33 # Redis settings

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.pyc in __getattr__(self, name)
     53     def __getattr__(self, name):
     54         if self._wrapped is empty:
---> 55             self._setup(name)
     56         return getattr(self._wrapped, name)
     57 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.pyc in _setup(self, name)
     39                 "You must either define the environment variable %s "
     40                 "or call settings.configure() before accessing settings."
---> 41                 % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
     42 
     43         self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)

ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Comment: did you put sorl-thumbnail in the installed apps in your settings file?